# MySQL Query: Values from multiple cells in a single cell

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

There is a table name `agents` which contains a list of agents and another table named `projects,` which contain list of projects and IDs of agent working on that project.

The output I am looking for is a list of agents, a total count of projects they are managing and list of projects.

Sample tables:

`agents`

```
AgentID     AgentName
------      ---------
1           Name1
2           Name2
3           Name3
```

`projects`

```
ProjectID    ProjectName   agentID
---------    -----------   -------
1            PName1        2
2            PName2        3
3            PName3        2
```

Desired output:

```
AgentName   No. of Projects   ProjectNames
---------   ---------------   ------------
Name2       2                 PName1
                              PName3
Name3       1                 PName2
```

Using the below query I am able to concatenate all projects in one cell..

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(projectName SEPARATOR ' , ') AS project_name FROM projects
```

But how can I concatenate projects linked to 1 agent... (as shown in the desired output table)?

Is there any solution to this problem?

I'll appreciate any help from this community...

Comment: Do you require this exact formatting?

Comment: Yes, as i want to show it as a report..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(projectName SEPARATOR ' , ') AS project_name, a.AgentID
FROM   projects p
       join agents a on (p.AgentID = a.AgentID)
GROUP BY a.AgentID
```

Comment: thanks its working.. but is it possible to get one project in one line?

Comment: try to play with separator. It will not affect in workbench, but an application'll move data to next row